# Visual Studio 2010 Font size change control + mouse wheel 1080p res monitor

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I recently bought a 1080p monitor and I'm still not used to the resolution. The default font size, Consolas 10, is too small for me to read and 11 is a bit bigger than I want it to be. 
If I increase the font with control + mouse wheel while the enviroment font size is 10, it gets bigger than I want it. The font size I'm ok with is 11 with one control + mouse wheel step decrement, but that is a little bit bigger than the default Consolas 10.

I'm wondering if the control + mouse wheel increments/decrements the text editor's font size by 1,5 value. How can I set it to the one I'm comfortable with? (Consolas 11 decremented by 1 control + mouse wheel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way that I have found to achieve this is to install [VSCommands](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf?SRC=VSIDE).  This tool allows you to set a default zoom level.  I think if you install this extension, set the default zoom level to 91% and set your font size to 11, it should give you what you need.

Comment: Right my bad, zoom level it is then. Marked as answer as from what I read there isn't a way to set a default zoom level other than by using an extension(?). Thank you both for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

When you hold ctrl and scroll the mouse wheel it doesn't change the font size, it changes the zoom level.

Use a combination of font size and zoom to achieve what you want.